# Jquery: has title but not word

Tags: jquery, search

How do i do a JQUERY select for this:

```
All images that have a title that does not have the word “dog” in it
```

I can select all images that have a title with this code:`

```
$('img[title]')
```

i have done this but its not working:

```
$('img[title]:not(title~="dog")')
or
$('img[title~="dog"]:not()')
or
$('img[title~="dog"]') //this selects the one with dog, but how do i do oposite of this
```

Comment: `$('img[title]:not([title~="dog"]);` I believe.

Comment: @Zulu how does your duplicate even come close to what OP is asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('img[title]:not([title~="dog"])')
```

you were close but the attribute part needs to be wrapped in `[]`

An alternative is use `filter()`

```
$('img[title]').filter(function(){
     return this.title.indexOf('dog') === -1;
});
```